# animation with images in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have a sequence of images that can be used as an animation if played one after another.
Which is the most efficient way to accomplish it with cocos2d?

An example would be appreciated!

(I am targeting iPod, iPhone && iPad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is everything you need to know, example code included: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d

Answer (score 1):

There are examples coming with cocos2d libs. There is an animation example